# Impossible to find Angular main module of my private library from an application since a specific version

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, shared-libraries

1. I had no problem to use my library (0.17.23) inside an application
   until the new version (0.17.24).
2. I had no error when I build my library in 0.17.24 : `ng build my-lib --prod`
   and i published it.
3. I had no error when I update it inside the external application :
   `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

...But when I run `ng serve` on local server I got this new error :

> Error: ./node_modules/@my-organization/my-lib/fesm2015/my-organization-my-lib.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'my-main-module' in 'D:\path-to-project\node_modules@my-organization\my-lib\fesm2015'

I have no log more so I'm little lost to understand what happens, someone has got an explanation and solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and the solution.

How I found the answer ?

1. I investigated the file `./node_modules/@my-organization/my-lib/fesm2015/my-organization-my-lib.js` about an import of `my-main-module`.
2. I compared this file with the same one of 0.17.23 version (the stable one) and I saw that line with the matter should not be there.
3. As the import was link with a specific typescript service file, I made a link with a warning (when I run the app to test the library locally with Ivy) about a `Circular dependency detected`
4. I fixed this `Circular Dependency` and that worked !